# Many to Many LINQ TO SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables:

Users
Roles
UserRoles
MenuItems
RoleMenuItems

A User can have multiple Roles and a MenuItem can be accessed by multiple Roles. Now I want to write a method as follows:

```
public IList<MenuItems> GetMenuItems(UserRoles userRoles)
{
   var menus = // LINQ query to get the MenuItems by UserRoles 

   return menus.ToList();
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't forget to flag your favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

userRoles.SelectMany(i => i.MenuItems);